# react calling function in onclick all the time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So I am using reactjs and node to make a website. In this one component that is meant to be a login button, it keeps track of whether the user is logged in or not using another class/object I have defined elsewhere. The problem is that I set it to call a logout function on click when the person is logged in (as well as say logout instead of login) but **this onClick function is triggering instantly upon the button being clicked once**.

```js
class LoginButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (AuthService.isAuthed() === false) {
      return (
        <li className="menu_button">
          <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        </li>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <li className="menu_button">
          <a href="/" onClick={console.log('Attempted to logout!')}>
            Logout
          </a>
        </li>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I changed the logout function to just a console.log() to know everytime its being called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your onClick method needs to be a function, not the result of executing a function. Something like:

```
function onClick() {
    console.log("Attempted to logout!")
}

<a href="/" onClick={ onClick }>
```

In ES-6 you could do

```
<a href="/" onClick={ () => console.log("Attempted to logout!") }>
```

Comment: My onclick was a function, it was AuthService.logout() which would log the user out but for some reason it gets instantly called without the user hitting the logout button and i know the call comes from the onClick block there since when i changed it to console.log() it would console.log() instead of logout.

Comment: `AuthService.logout` is a function, but when you add the `()` at the end, the value becomes the result of calling the function.

Comment: Notice the only difference in the ES6 example above and your question is the added `() =>` before, which makes it an anonymous function object.